# Using magic "ed" in IPython without running a script afterwards

Tags: editor, ipython

When I use `ed` in IPython, I have got my script running after closing the editor. Is it possible to edit without running afterward in IPython?

Actually, I would like to have both options.

Comment: `%edit -x` tells it not to execute afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. That is what i needed. Where is it written?

Comment: The easiest way to find it is to do `%edit?` (you can append ? to most things in IPython for more information)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%edit -x`

```
[1]: %edit? 

-x: do not execute the edited code immediately upon exit. This is 
mainly useful if you are editing programs which need to be called with
command line arguments, which you can then do using %run.
```